# Redirect happens when clicked inside of the <a> tag, despite $event.stopPropagation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Template:

```
<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">
  Documentation <i ng-click="$ctrl.hideDocumentation($event)" class="fa fa-times remove"></i>
</a>
```

Controller:

```
function hideDocumentation($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  ///// MAKE SOME API CALLS
}
```

How do I prevent redirection to `https://example.com/` when I click on the `<i>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know angular, but `$event.preventDefault()` might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

something like ( i am so used to react):

```
<a href="" target="_blank" onClick="handleClickFunction">
  Documentation <i ng-click="$ctrl.hideDocumentation($event)" class="fa fa-times remove</i>
</a>

function hideDocumentation($event) {
  $event.stopPropagation();
  ///// MAKE SOME API CALLS
}
```

ie: move your clickHandler to the actual `<a/>` it is still firing and doing exactly what it is designed to to which is to navigate... if you want to still navigate after doing some things you can then use `window.location = www.next-location.com` from inside the click handler.

by wrapping your icon in a a tag you are essentially making it an link... but it seems you need to distinguish behaviors. it seems to me that these should be separated all together if possible. blindly calling preventDefault may have unexpected behaviors for when you *do* want to navigate. I would create a single `onClick` handler that determines what needs to happen in both scenarios. you can *possibly* just read exactly what was clicked (a or i) or do something like this to determine what exactly was clicked:

```
<a href="" target="_blank" onClick="($event) => $handleClick($event, 'a')">
  Documentation <i ng-click="$handleClick($event, 'i')" class="fa fa-times remove</i>
</a>

function hideDocumentation($event, el) {
  if (el === 'a') { 
    window.location = www.next-location.com 
    return
  }

  // else handle the non-nav scenario

  $event.preventDefault();
  $ctrl.hideDocumentation
  ///// MAKE SOME API CALLS
}
```

Comment: well then thing is that `hideDocumentation` method should be called only when you click on the `x` icon (fa-times). Otherwise it should navigate to the URL

Comment: then you may need to read the event to see which element was clicked and make the appropriate action in the clickHandler, but you still need to handle it all in the click handler else this will keep navigating...i will update my answer with one option